# Feeding Data in an Excel Template with visual studio Windows Form C++ program

Tags: excel, visual-studio-2010

I started a projet of automatic reporting. To realize this i am using Microsft Visual Studio 2010 C++ (Ultimate edition)

Right now the project is almost finish, but i am getting stuck at the last step.

What i would like to do is to create a C++ function (called by a button in my windows form) which open a connexion to SQL server (it's done) make some SELECT statement, and put these results in an ALREADY existing Excel file (which is a template with only header / colors, etc...)

The connexion to the SQL server is done and working, but i am wondering how can i be able to put data in the excel Cells i want ? I connected my excel file with Server Explorer but it's display as a Empty database.

I'd like to know if some of you already did this kind of stuff, i am open to other ideas as well, Another idea for me would have been to feed the excel file with a dtsx, which would be run in my C++ function called by the ButtonClickEvent.

I also found xlslib http://xlslib.sourceforge.net/ but i am not very good with dll/lib, and it seems that when i open the solution downloaded, and i try to run it to create dll/lib, it got some error... so i took this idea away for the moment.

Thank you very much for your help !

Comment: A similar question has some answers that may be useful to you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7326785/get-data-into-excel-from-winform?rq=1

Comment: Thank you for your answer i am checking that